# Show More text in android when the users click on it

Tags: android, text

I was hoping I could get some help with this.

I would like to have an 'see more' option in android. E.G when the users click on a text, it should open up and display more text on what they clicked on.

For example, there is an an question and when the users click on it, it displays info for that question, and when clicked on again it hides that. I have no idea on how to do this, expact that I maybe can use **ListView** with **ArrayAdapter**.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for https://sites.google.com/site/androidappcourse/labs/lab-3

Section 2.2

Answer (score 1):

one quick answer for this is,

1)add one quick textview say view1 in your xml layout.

2)make this views visibility hidden/gone.

3) when user click on your first textview. make view1 visible  and set text which you wanna show.

4) after user again click on this view make it invisible and reset the text.